# Android In-App Purchase Costs More In My Country

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

Recently I made an in-app purchase in the very popular SuperCell game Clash Royale where I bought some Gems for $11.18.

I later realized that players in the USA paid $9.99 for the same item so I was wondering...why does the same item cost more to purchase from my country on Google Play? Does Google charge depending on the region or country?

I live in the Caribbean, we use USD to make In-App purchases from Google Play.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167552/12442

Comment: I hate this, I have to pay $31 in my currency for a pack that costs $24.99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pricing is *market specific*

From [Google Developer help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373) targetting app developers :

> We'll use the price you enter as the base for calculating market-specific prices. We'll convert your price to the local currency, add tax (in select countries), and apply locally relevant pricing patterns.

Though this is mentioned in context of pricing of apps, logically it should hold for *in app* purchases too

Comment: Do Americans also pay taxes for in-app purchases, or does the price listed really match the price paid for them?

Comment: @Qwerty no idea. I live in India