# How to get cheap In app purchases

Tags: google-play-games

Does anyone know where it is cheapest in the work to buy in app purchases from?

I've seen people try Brazil, Russia, etc..

Well on android, if you change your local settings to a different country in your google wallet as well, for example Mexico you can buy things slightly cheaper than say in the U.S.

A lot of games have packs that you can purchase and they are very expensive especially for Things like Game of War or Mobile Strike.

A lot of people get things for cheaper. But when their gold reaches 50 k, the pack price changes and for some reason it no longer works.. so they can't get cheaper packs..

I was wondering if anyone knows a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Prices are set by each app developer for each country separately, so the price difference between countries will be different for each app.

By default, Google Play sets the price in each country according to the exchange rate for the currency, so it will be effectively the same price everywhere. The app developer can override this for any country, separately for each app, so it's up to the developer's pricing policy. The developer can change the prices as often as they like, so a country that's cheaper one day might be more expensive the next day.